# Конвертация базы XML в формат MySQL

Tags: xml, mysql, sql

Есть база на 1.5 gb в формате XML. Чем её можно конвертнуть в формат mySQL? Подскажите, кто знает.

Comment: http://www.html.by/threads/1717-parsing-iz-xml-v-mysql

Comment: круто. но не изобрели еще ли просто софта для этого дела? каждый раз писать скрипт замучаешься мне...

Answer (score 2):

При условии, что таблица с подходящей структурой уже создана в MySQL, можно в консоли mysql:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'database.xml' 
INTO TABLE datatable 
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<datarow>';
```

- database.xml - имя файла,
- datatable - имя таблицы,
- datarow - элемент XML, который должен сотвествователь импортируемым данным.